# Cannot put children in ItemsControl in XAML - "Content can only be set once"

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have created an UserControl whose LayoutRoot is ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel, but now I can't add my shapes in it.

Also I had a working Canvas inside a Border, but when I tried to remove the canvas Children and transform the Border + Canvas into an UserControl, I cannot anymore add the children back, because "Content can only be set once".

Here is my code:

Before (working, but I have to create an UserControl for reuse):

```
    <Border>
        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderTransform="{StaticResource ViewTransform}">
            <Polygon .../>                  
            <Path ...>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
```

Current form, not working, with a control with identical structure as above, having `Canvas` as innermost element. The error is "content can only be set once":

```
    <local:TentativeViewportControl>            
        <Polygon.../>                   
        <Path .../>
    </local:ItemsViewportControl>
```

The more recent try, now with ItemsPanel as UserControl root panel, not working too:

```
<ItemsControl/>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" ... />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>      
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the error message. A Border can only have one child. If you want to add multiple things, you will have to wrap them in a panel that allows multiple children (e.g. Grid).

Something like this,

```
<Border>
    <ContentContainer><!-- Grid, or StackPanel, or whatever you choose -->
        <Object/>
        <Object/>
        <OBject/>
    </ContentContainer>
</Border>
```

Comment: Well, my code is exactely like yours. My innermost panels are always Canvas, which are inside the Border. The Border is there only to layout the Canvas itself.

Comment: Check your usercontrol again!